# "setup can't copy files" error during XP installation

Tags: windows-xp, installation, setup

During installing Windows XP, I got errors like "Setup can't copy `ks.sys`, `modem.sys` etc...etc.."

I skipped the error messages, but after all that Windows XP is not detecting cd drive or USB. How to solve this?

Answer (score 2):

If you can't install an OS from scratch either:

- the installation media is bad
- the DVD drive is bad
- the computer hardware is fundamentally unstable

It is very, *very* bad when you cannot perform a clean install of an OS -- that is the most basic test of "is this computer actually working?"

Answer (score 1):

simply buy a new CD for XP this one is faulty

Answer (score 0):

You might try using a linux live cd and see if that works. Most likely causes of your problem are bad cd or bad drive. A bad computer is also possible but less likely, assuming that it worked before you tried reinstalling the OS.

Answer (score -1):

Make sure that your Installation cd/dvd can support your hard drive type (such as SATA) 
Use a compatible one (download windows xp sp3, sata driver included) from the internet .

Answer (score -1):

It means that there is a problem with your system's Random Access Memory (RAM).

You should try replacing your system RAM and run the Windows XP installation program again.